# Any Android libraries which implement Facebook's Yoga layout engine?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-engine

I'm interested in any Android implementations of Facebook's Yoga layout engine which allows me to add any View to it and have it defined by the Yoga's layout.

Something similar to the YogaLayout (which unfortunately was removed by Facebook, it's only as part of ReactNative).

I am already aware of the FlexboxLayout (https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).